# How to curl access RASA NLU (starter-pack-rasa-stack)?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

With this link https://github.com/RasaHQ/starter-pack-rasa-stack

I've managed to launch the server with this command : **make cmdline** and test it with **succeeded**!

What if I would like to access my bot server with **Postman** or **curl command** Is is possible or do I have to write additional code?

Here are my approach:

1.make action-server

```
Narongs-MacBook-Pro:starter-pack-rasa-stack softmastx$ make action-server
python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions
INFO:__main__:Starting action endpoint server...
ERROR:rasa_core_sdk.executor:Failed to register package 'actions'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasa_core_sdk/executor.py", line 144, in register_package
    self._import_submodules(package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasa_core_sdk/executor.py", line 131, in _import_submodules
    package = importlib.import_module(package)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "actions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from rasa_core.channels.direct import CollectingOutputChannel
ImportError: No module named direct
INFO:__main__:Action endpoint is up and running. on ('0.0.0.0', 5055)
```

2.make cmdline

```
2018-10-12 08:22:20.869093: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-10-12 08:22:22 INFO     root  - Rasa Core server is up and running on http://localhost:5005
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`make cmdline` does not start an extra NLU server. So you cannot directly curl the Rasa NLU API.
However, you can send messages directly to Core:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "message": "Hello"
}'
```

If you want to start an extra NLU server you have to run:

```
python -m rasa_nlu.server --path models/current
```

You can then curl Rasa NLU with:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'http://localhost:5000/parse?q=Hello&project=nlu'
```

Comment: what does the project=nlu mean ? how do i find name of my project ?